# Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

**I have this trouble and i cannot solve it with JNDI**
**class ITCenterManagementPersistenceBeanRemote**

```
public interface ITCenterManagementPersistenceBeanRemote {
public void insertStudent(long id, String name, String birthday, String address, String phonenumber, String email);
public void insertStudent(long id, String name, String birthday, String address, String phonenumber, String email);}
```

**class ITCenterManagementPersistenceBean**

```
    @Stateless
    public class ITCenterManagementPersistenceBean implements ITCenterManagementPersistenceBeanRemote {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "QuanLiTTTinHocPU")
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        public ITCenterManagementPersistenceBean() {

        }

        @Override
        public void insertStudent(long id, String name, String birthday, String address, String phonenumber, String email) {
            Student s = new Student(id, name, birthday, address, phonenumber, email);
            entityManager.persist(s);
        }
@Override
    public List<Student> getStudent() {
        return entityManager.createNamedQuery("Student.findAll").getResultList();
    }}
```

**test class**

```
public class ITCenterManagementTester {

private Properties props;
private InitialContext ctx;

public ITCenterManagementTester() {
    readJNDI();
}

private void readJNDI() {
    props = new Properties();

    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream("jndi.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }

    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        //ctx.close();
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
}

private String getJNDI() {
    String appName = "";
    String moduleName = "QuanLiTTTinHoc";
    String distinctName = "";
    String sessionBeanName = ITCenterManagementPersistenceBean.class.getSimpleName();
    String viewClassName = ITCenterManagementPersistenceBeanRemote.class.getName();

    return "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + sessionBeanName + "!" + viewClassName;
}

private void showGUI() {
    System.out.println("\n===============================");
    System.out.println("Welcome to IT center Management");
    System.out.println("===============================");
    System.out.print("Options: \n1. student \n2. List All student \n3. Teacher \n4. List all Tacher"
            + "\n5. Staff \n6. List all Staff \n7. Add class \n8. List of class\n9. Add Subject"
            + "\n10. Add Class Shift \n11. Class Shift list \n12. Add Prerequisite Subject \n13. Add Schedule \n14. Add Exam Schedule"
            + "\n15. Add Result \n16. Addtendance \n17. Teaching Schedule \n18. Add Register Information"
            + "\n19. List of Register Information\n20. Exit \nEnter Choice: ");
}

/*private void getAllBooks() {
    try {
        // We can define another bean to access the LibrarySessionBeanRemote
        ITCenterManagementPersistenceBeanRemote CenterBean2 = (ITCenterManagementPersistenceBeanRemote) ctx.lookup(getJNDI());
        //List<String> studentList = CenterBean2.getStudent();

        // Print all books
        System.out.println("\n===============================");
        System.out.println("Listing Student");
        System.out.println("===============================");
        //for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
        //    System.out.println(i + "\t" + studentList.get(i));
        //}
        System.out.println("");

    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
}*/
public void testStatelessEJB() {
    try {
        // Scanner definition
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // ITCenterManagementPersistenceBeanRemote
        ITCenterManagementPersistenceBeanRemote session = (ITCenterManagementPersistenceBeanRemote) ctx.lookup(getJNDI());

        int choice = 0;
        long studentID;
        String name;
        String birthday;
        String address;
        String phonenumber;
        String email;
        Subject subjectName;
        long classID;
        String className;
        Date beginDay;
        Date endDay;
        BigInteger stdNumber;
        BigInteger fee;
        long shiftID;
        String shiftName;
        String beginTime;
        String endTime;
        double point;
        long PSubjectID;
        boolean absent;
        Date absentDate;
        Staff staffID;
        long registerID;
        Date registerDate;
        ClassShift ShiftID;
        Date testDate;
        String time;
        BigInteger hour;
        String room;
        do {
            showGUI();
            choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("insert Student ID: ");
                    studentID = Long.parseLong(sc.nextLine()) ;
                    System.out.print("insert Student name: ");
                    name = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("insert Student birthday: ");
                    birthday = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("insert Student address: ");
                    address = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("insert Student phone number: ");
                    phonenumber = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("insert Student email: ");
                    email = sc.nextLine();
                    session.insertStudent(studentID, name, birthday, address, phonenumber, email);
                    System.out.println("Done!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    List<Student> s = session.getStudent();
                    if (s.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("There is no student in list!");
                    }
                    System.out.println("\n=========================");
                    System.out.println("Listing Student");
                    System.out.println("=========================");
                    for(int i = 0; i<s.size();i++){
                        System.out.println((i+1)+"\t"+s.get(i));
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
        } while (choice != 50);

    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

}

**

> this is class student

**

```
package edu.tdt.persistence;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author MSI
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student", catalog = "ITCenterManagement", schema = "public")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByStudentID", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.studentID = :studentID")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByName", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.name = :name")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByBirthDay", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.birthDay = :birthDay")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByAddress", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.address = :address")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByPhoneNumber", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.phoneNumber = :phoneNumber")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByEmail", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.email = :email")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByA", query = "SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.a = :a")})
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "Birthday", length = 2147483647)
    private String birthday;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "PhoneNumber", length = 2147483647)
    private String phoneNumber;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "StudentID", nullable = false)
    private Long studentID;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "Name", length = 2147483647)
    private String name;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "BirthDay", length = 2147483647)
    private String birthDay;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "Address", length = 2147483647)
    private String address;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "Email", length = 2147483647)
    private String email;
    @Size(max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "", length = 2147483647)
    private String a;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student")
    private Collection<Attendance> attendanceCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentID")
    private Collection<RegisterInformation> registerInformationCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student")
    private Collection<TestResult> testResultCollection;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(long studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;

    }

    public Student(long studentID, String name, String birthday, String address, String phonenumber, String email) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDay = birthday;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phonenumber;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public void setStudentID(Long studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBirthDay() {
        return birthDay;
    }

    public void setBirthDay(String birthDay) {
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Attendance> getAttendanceCollection() {
        return attendanceCollection;
    }

    public void setAttendanceCollection(Collection<Attendance> attendanceCollection) {
        this.attendanceCollection = attendanceCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<RegisterInformation> getRegisterInformationCollection() {
        return registerInformationCollection;
    }

    public void setRegisterInformationCollection(Collection<RegisterInformation> registerInformationCollection) {
        this.registerInformationCollection = registerInformationCollection;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<TestResult> getTestResultCollection() {
        return testResultCollection;
    }

    public void setTestResultCollection(Collection<TestResult> testResultCollection) {
        this.testResultCollection = testResultCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (studentID != null ? studentID.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Student)) {
            return false;
        }
        Student other = (Student) object;
        if ((this.studentID == null && other.studentID != null) || (this.studentID != null && !this.studentID.equals(other.studentID))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "edu.tdt.persistence.Student[ studentID=" + studentID + " ]";
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

main

```
public class QuanLiTTTinHocTester {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws EJBException, IllegalStateException{
        // TODO code application logic here
        ITCenterManagementTester test = new ITCenterManagementTester();
        test.testStatelessEJB();
    }

}
```

when i run main and i recieve this error

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:238)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getStudent(Unknown Source)
    at edu.tdt.test.ITCenterManagementTester.testStatelessEJB(ITCenterManagementTester.java:153)
    at edu.tdt.test.QuanLiTTTinHocTester.main(QuanLiTTTinHocTester.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:131)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:112)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:948)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1255)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1745)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(RiverObjectInputStream.java:81)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:914)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callReadObject(SerializableClass.java:307)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1637)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1606)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.InvocationExceptionResponseHandler$MethodInvocationExceptionResultProducer.getResult(InvocationExceptionResponseHandler.java:79)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:276)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBObjectInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(EJBObjectInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:290)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBHomeInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(EJBHomeInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:290)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:290)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(ReceiverInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:265)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:453)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:204)
    ... 5 more
C:\Users\MSI\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

*
i implement student class form postgresql and so do the other but i just example with the student class first. when i run test project and it show the error but i don't know how to solve.

> i don't know why, so please help!

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client needs to have the JPA api classes on it's class path.

Your call to the EJB is failing with a `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` which is being propagated to the client.

The client then fails because it can't find that class in it's class path.

Comment: so how can I fix it, i device it into 2 project: one i make it to be EJB project, another is test project. so what should i do to fix it.

Comment: You need to find the jar containing `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` and add it to your test project.

Comment: Can I have another favor that after add and i have another problem about org.hibernate.wxception.SQLGrammarException. how can I fix it

Comment: Ask this in a new question please